# 100% pixel perfect Displacement map

Tags: displacement

I'm not a highly skilled Blender user, so maybe it's a dumb question:
So shortly: how can I put my displacement map (a  square image) onto my plane (square too) matched perfectly?

With detailes: I'm in a middle of a project, what is 100% planned, and described mathematically, and it's going well, but now I need a displacement map, and I'm disappointed when I'm tryin to find out, how to put my perfect square map into the displacement modifier of my perfect square plane, if I want it to match perfectly. I have several ideas with displacement maps, but without this I can't really make them real.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Hello :). A new plane comes automatically with a UV map like that. You just need to select a UV map in your Displacement Modifier settings

Comment: sorry, where? texture / coordinates / direction / strength / midlevel / vertex group
that's all - I don't really see where this modifier connects to UV. Anyway, thank you for your comment, I'll try to find it out

Comment: It's in Displace Modifier > Coordinates > UV ;)

Comment: yes, it's ok now! Thank you for your help, I choose the next answer, I know, you wrote the same thing, but I needed those details, to solve the problem. I'm on it to learn the whole process, and don't ask dumb questions again, and again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you make a UV map for your plain (plane?)?
If I understand correctly, your plane is square in the projection along the z-axis.
You could switch to top view, switch to edit mode, UV-unwrap with the option "project from view (bounds)". This should line up everything neatly.
Maybe you'll have to rotate the UV map in the UV editor by some multiple of 90 degrees afterwards, but the size and relative position should match then.

This is how you set the texture coordinates to use the UVMap:
[image]

Or maybe upload your blendfile, so we can have a better look?

Comment: yes plane, sorry (it's fixed) - it's an empty plane (6x6m) and a displacement map modifier, with the image as you see on the picture. I've tried the UV thing, didn't help, with the crop  on the texture tab I can position the displacements, I don't see the uv maps, displacement modifier connection, there's nothing about it in the docs, but thank you for your help, I'll try it again after some reading and/or tutorial

Comment: Check the edit I made, it shows how to use the UV Map as texture coordinate

Comment: yes, it's ok now, thanks!

Comment: Also keep in mind that displacement needs vertices to operate on. A simple plane won't only four vertices will not deform, use a subdivision surface modifier before the displacement modifier.